# "J" message type in Nasdaq ITCH Totalview sample file

Tags: equities, market-data, market-microstructure, nasdaq, feed

I am trying to parse the uncompressed file 10302018.NASDAQ_ITCH50 (from ftp://emi.nasdaq.com/ITCH/10302018.NASDAQ_ITCH50.gz). 
There is a strange message type "J". The spec (https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/NQTVITCHspecification.pdf) does not contain any format for "J" message type. Is this corrupt data?

Answer (score 2):

4.2.7  Limit Up – Limit Down (LULD) Auction Collar

Indicates the auction collar thresholds within which a paused security can reopen following a LULD Trading Pause

```
Name Offset Length Value Notes
Message Type 0 1 “J” LULD Auction Collar
```

Comment: https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalsupport/specifications/dataproducts/TVAggSpecification.pdf Page 11